# Convert to date from foo.year, foo.month, foo.day with pure SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to build a SQL query, which in pseudo code would look like:

```
SELECT foo.id 
FROM foo, bar
WHERE foo.some_date < "#{Date.new(bar.year, bar.month, bar.day)}"
```

As shown above, this can be easily done with a programming language, but for this particular use case, ideally I would like to do it in pure SQL. Is this even possible?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use [`make_date()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html):

```
select make_date(bar.year, bar.month, bar.day)
```

(Well, this assumes that `bar` is a table alias in the query.)